# Keeping SQL Server Dev Environment up to date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, development-environment, database-restore

I'm trying to figure out the best way to keep my Development servers synced up to the Production servers. Initially, I was just going to restore the backups from the production environment to the dev environment every week or so, however I realized that this would wipe out any actual development work that had taken place during the week.

I feel like this is a pretty common obstacle, so I'm hoping someone out there can shed some light on how they tackle the issue. I looked online briefly, but didn't really see anything, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/index.htm) have a couple of products that you might want to look at:

- [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/)
- [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/)

They allow you to compare and synchronize schemas and data respectively between two databases.

Answer (score 1):

Any change made to the development environment should, at some point, be pushed to production. Therefore, each change made on the dev environment must exist as a patch (sql script). To keep dev in sync with production you just restore the production backup and apply all the newly developed patches.